# How do I package a class that extends App with sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I need to test a module that uses stdin.  The module has a main and a class that extends App.  Is there a way to build and package only the class that extend App?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set main class in `built.sbt` for using specific class or object as main entry for your program.

```
mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("Package.Main")
```

If you only want to package specific main class and exclude other from packaging, see the `excludeFilter` option.